# Where is magnifying glass button came from

Tags: flutter

During inspecting scaffold Flutter project (without any modification) with Flutter Inspector in some cases of toggling widgets in left bottom corner magnifying glass button appear.

Where is it come from and what is its purpose?

Attached screenshots show that this button exists only on Render Tree tab.

[image: Android emulator]
[image: Widgets]
[image: Render Tree]

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: @dhuma1981 this is default Flutter Application which produced by Android Studio Flutter plugin on creating a new project without any modification in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This button appears only after you turned on "Select Widget Mode" in Flutter Inspector and selected a first widget to inspect. In order to inspect another widget you first need to tap the magnifier FAB.